# fflush\flushall()\_flushall() and etc won't clear buffer in C

Tags: c, visual-studio

In all the programs I'm required to do for a project I encounter an input buffer problem, so far I cleaned it with a while loop but I've been told now not to do so (You can see it commented out).

I tried using flushall(), _flushall() and all the alternatives that Visual Studio offers me but none of them cut it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    while (speed <= 0 || distance <= 0 || (distance == -1 || speed == -1))
    {

        scanf(" %d %d", &distance, &speed);
        //while (getchar() != '\n');


   }
```

Comment: `fflush(<inout stream>)` is UB [according to the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2p2).

Comment: scanf() was never meant for humans, use fgets() and sscanf() instead.

Comment: Who's telling you to not clear out the input stream this way?  And what are they recommending in its place?

Comment: Also, define "none of them cut it" - does the code not build?  Not run?  Not clear the input stream?  What behavior to you *expect*, and what behavior do you *get*?  Are you linking your code with COMMODE.OBJ (per [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx))?

Comment: My teacher ironically. The input stream isnt cleared and the next scanf takes the data and stays in the loop, the exact code above^ (distances and speed are -1 for that matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real technique, in most circumstances, is not to try to flush `stdin` at all.

To do that, it is necessary to interact with `stdin` in the same way, every time.   In practice, that normally amounts to not mixing styles of input.

If using formatted input (like `scanf()`), never use line-oriented input (e.g. `fgets()`) or character oriented input (e.g. `getc()`) on the same stream.   Similarly, if using `fgets()` to read, never use formatted input or character-oriented input on the same stream.

And so on.

The reason is that different styles of input respond differently to some specific characters - particularly to newline and whitespace.  When you mix those styles of input, there are unwanted interactions.   `scanf()`, for example, will often stop reading if it encounters a newline (`'\n'`), and leave that newline in the stream.   `fgets()` on the other hand will also stop as soon as it reaches a newline, but remove that newline from the stream.   Hence if there is a `scanf()` call followed by a `fgets( ..., stdin)`, the `fgets()` call will often return immediately - without reading the data that was expected.

Furthermore, if using `scanf()`, it is necessary to be careful with choice of format strings, to avoid some interactions between subsequent calls as well.

Answer (score 2):

The stdio "flush" operation (`fflush`) has nothing to do with "clearing buffers". It merely causes data buffered for write to be written out to the actual file. If you want to discard input (e.g. to the end of the line), write code to discard input.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as I mentioned, I used the commented while loop to discard the input stream before but I've been told not to do so for this project. I can't find any information online on why it wouldn't work seeing as many beginner C courses recommend using flushall() after scanf\getchar().

Comment: @JonathanLeon - Anyone recommending using any of the `flush()` calls to clear input does not understand what they're saying.  Per the C standard:  "**If stream points to an output stream or an update stream** in which the most recent operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**"  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: @JonathanLeon: Who told you not to? There are other ways you can achieve the same thing, e.g. just adding to the end of your `scanf` format string: `"%*[^\n]%*c"`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx), Visual Studio's implementation of `fflush` can be used to clear an input stream: "If the stream is open for input, `fflush` clears the contents of the buffer."  This, of course, is wrongheaded and backward and non-portable, but, you know, Microsoft.